# App Icon not on desktop

Tags: android

I have tried everything but when i install my android app from USB. The shortcut on desktop is not created. Please Help.

Following is my code:

```
  private void createShortcutOnDesktop(Application app) {

       Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent();
       shortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, app.getIntentShortcut());
       shortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, app.getName());
       shortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(context, R.drawable.home_button));
       shortcutIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
       this.sendBroadcast(shortcutIntent);
       finish();
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your manifest file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the installation from **Play store** facilitates this thing.  For that you need to add following permission to your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
```

Comment: I don't think its necessary to add this line. Its automatically gets created even if you don't add this line.

Comment: but sometimes it creates a problem for some devices as i have self experienced the same.

Comment: could you be more specific (what range of devices e.t.c)? Actually i also have few apps on google play but haven't received such kinda issue report yet.